# formatting the x axis to % and the y axis to £

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have used this python code in Power BI:

```
colors = ["#FF0B04", "#ffbf00", "#228800"]
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
g = sns.JointGrid(data=dataset, x="Score", y="Profit", hue= 'Score Bands')
g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot,legend=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

to create the plot:
[image]

Can anybody please help on formatting the x axis to % and the y axis to £?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sample data from the official site, I associated seaborn with ax, and then used formatter to specify the percentage display and euro currency symbol in unicode.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
colors = ["#FF0B04", "#ffbf00", "#228800"]
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
g = sns.JointGrid(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue= 'time')
g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot,legend=False)
ax = g.ax_joint

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("\u20ac%d"))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. My last challenge is to format the y axis tick labels to e.g. £10K. With your code slightly modified code: 
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("£%d"))    

 it comes as £10000. I have also tried a different method:      
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.0f}'.format(x/1000) + 'K'))    

 but it results to 10K without the currency symbol. If you could show me how tol get the full £10K that would be a great.

Comment: Putting in a currency indication or a unique notation should be specified in the previous string, rather than handled by an argument. `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '\u20ac{:,.0f}K'.format(x/1000))) `